# Magento 2 does not upload files and views after installation

Tags: php, magento2

Install magento 2 but the home view and admin to login do not load well or nothing is seen, in the console there are several errors that no files were found.

I already ran the following commands in the root of the project:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But it still does not work. How can I solve this problem?

These are the errors that appear to me

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about the permission for pub and var folders

Answer (score 0):

What is your locale/language? You should deploy content with the specific locale.
Example, I want to deploy theme for Australia, I will run this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU
```

Regards